# How can you turn off size randomisation of particles?

Tags: particles

I am doing the donut beginner tutorial. My sprinkles/particles vary in size, but they shouldn´t. Where can I change that?
[image]

Comment: In the render tab, there's a setting _Scale Randomness_.  Set it to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Select your Emitter object, tap on "particle properties", then on "render" and change the "scale randomeness" value:

[image]